# Is it possible to use genetic algorithms as a learning algorithm for artificial neural networks?

Tags: neural-networks, optimization, genetic-algorithms

I've been using back-propagation to optimize neural networks without problems. But I've read in some books that genetic algorithms can be used to optimize an ANN. I want to know if its possible to use them as a learning algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes!**
There are essentially 2 ways of doing that: with fixed topology or evolving topology.

Fixed topology is the easiest. Just encode all weights as values in your chromossomes and evolve. You can use the network error as your fitness (to minimize, in this case). The disadvantage of this method is that you need to chose the network architecture manually. You can see this approach in action [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=05rEefXlmhI).

But there is also the possibility of evolving the structure together with the weights. The most famous algorithm for this is [NEAT](http://www.cs.ucf.edu/~kstanley/neat.html). You can see it in action [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qv6UVOQ0F44) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iakFfOmanJU).

Comment: Thank you bro!! thats what i nedd. Do you speak spanish by the way??

Comment: Just portuguese! At most portunhol hehe

Comment: is it possible compare the performance of these two learning algorithms(Back-propagation and Genetic Algorithms)?What are the parameters that i can compare??

Comment: Yes, it is. It depends on your problem. For instance, if it is a classification task, you could compare the generalization accuracy of the best model obtained from each technique. You could also compare the training time or memory.

Comment: Thank you men, you are helping me a lot, And for prediction problem what parameter should i do??

Comment: Prediction is just a kind of classification or regression, so you use the same measures like accuracy and MSE. Also, time and memory can be applied to any kind of problem.